# Using BDD examples to introduce locators

Tags: angularjs, protractor, bdd

I am designing a scenario using BDD with Gherkin. I am working with protractor. One of the parameters is the locator of a button.
When trying to look for the button using locators, it doesn't find such button. See the feature below to better understanding:

```
Scenario Outline: main page of the application works, and when clicking on the button, the page is opened
    When open main page of the application
    And select the <button>
    Then application is running
    Examples:
    |button|
    |'[href="/template_definition"]'|
```

The code is:

```
When(/^select the (.*)/, function (button,callback)
    {
        HomePage.clickButton(button,callback);
    });
```

The step is the one above. Now, below is the code where I want to select the element whose css locator is contained within the 'button' variable. The question, is what should I write where the word 'button' is written to make it works.

```
clickButton: function(button,callback)
    {
        let el;
        el=element(by.css(button));
        el.click().then(function () {
            callback();
        });
    },
```

Comment: remove the `'` around `[href="/template_definition"]`,  the step parameter will be treated as string by default. Thus no need to put the locator within `'`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `'` around `[href="/template_definition"]`, the step parameter will be treated as string by default. Thus no need to put the locator within `'`